# Python can't run script inside package

Tags: python, file, terminal, module, package

I believe the problem is running the code not importing, as IntelliCode recognizes the module and functions

So here is the structure of my files

```
-a.py
-tests/
      -__init__.py
      -b.py
-pages/
      -__init__.py
      -c.py
```

Here is c.py

```
from tests import b


def hello_from_c():
    print('C says hi')
```

Here is b.py

```
import pages.c as c

c.hello_from_c()
```

When I run 'python a.py' in terminal with either b or c imported it runs fine.
However, when I run either c or b in terminal as a script, trying to import the other file, I get 'no module named tests' or 'no module named pages'. Even though IntelliCode is showing no errors.

What's the reason this is happening?

(Update)
running `python -m [packagename].[filename(no .py)]` works

Comment: `import ..tests`?

Comment: No, it recognizes the import as i can call functions. Its just when i run it in terminal i get the error

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I assume you have `import tests` inside `c.py` or `import pages` inside `b.py`

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: I added the code there, It doesnt seem to be problem importing its only when running

Comment: What does that mean? Importing is only done when you run the script that contains the `import` statement.

Comment: It should be `from ..tests import b`, as in the duplicate I linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `python a.py`, python searches for modules relative to the address `a.py` is in, which in your example is the root address. That is why you can import `b.py` and `c.py` using `tests.b` and `pages.c`, no matter which file the import code is in (be it `a.py`, `b.py`, or `c.py`).

However, when you run `b.py` or `c.py`, python's module search scope is relative to the address those files are in. Therefore, when you run `b.py`, it looks for a `pages` folder inside the `tests` folder, which obviously does not exists.

Even if you try using `..`, you will receive a `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. If you really want to import something from another python file in a sibling directory, I suggest you read this thread:

[How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)